# How to split a nested dictionay in evey two pairs (key,value) in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

i have this dictionary:

```
{1:{a:100,b:200,c:300,d:100},
 2:{e:100,f:200,g:300,h:100},
 3:{....}}
```

and i want to create it like this:

```
{1:{{a:100,b:200},{c:300,d:100}},
 2:{{e:100,f:200},{g:300,h:100}},
 3:{{....}}
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution but creates a list of dictionaries:

```
a={'995430643': {'a': '1', 'b': 'error', 'c': '1', 'd': '300'}, 
       '996245790': { 'e' : '1',  'f' : 'error',  'g' : '1',  'h' : '300'}, 
       '997667101': { 'k' : '1',  'l': 'error',  'm' : '1',  'n' : '300'}}
    
    aaa = {key: list(map(dict, zip(list(value.items())[::2], list(value.items())[1::2]))) for key, value in a.items()  }
    print(aaa)
```

"{'995430643': [{'a': '1', 'b': 'error'}, {'c': '1', 'd': '300'}], '996245790': [{'e': '1', 'f': 'error'}, {'g': '1', 'h': '300'}], '997667101': [{'k': '1', 'l': 'error'}, {'m': '1', 'n': '300'}]}"